# It there any linux system that does not tear or blur on multi display configuration?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, nvidia, display

I have a problem with screen blurring on one of my displays. Both of them are connected via DP cable. When I'm scrolling text or there is anything moving on that display, there is a visible blur. I was trying to solve it, trying to fin solution and cannot find any except using xinerama or TwinView, which does not seems to be perfect solution.

I'm currently using Linux Mint 19 Mate with Macro and Compton (also tried on fresh installed 18.3 Mate and 19.2 Mate).

Displays: 2x Dell U2419H

GPU: Nvidia RTX2070 with 430 drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tear/blur is just that the graphics card doesn't keep up with the change in the images to be displayed. Not nice, sure. But I very much doubt any software-based change (unless it is slower changes of stuff to display) will make any difference.

Comment: Yes, I was almost sure, that it happened on both displays, but couldn't reproduce this so I checked both displays on other machine and one of the displays has faulty DP port. That's 4th faulty Dell display for about 3 years.